# HDFS file blocks distribution in two node cluster

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Environment

Hadoop : 0.20.205.0
Number of machines in cluster : 2 nodes
Replication : set to 1
DFS Block size : 1MB

I put a 7.4MB file into HDFS using put command. I run fsck command to check the blocks distribution of the file among the datanodes. I see that all the 8 blocks of the file are going to only one node. This affects the load distribution and only one node always get used while running mapred tasks.

Is there a way that I can distribute the files to more than one datanode?

```
bin/hadoop dfsadmin -report
Configured Capacity: 4621738717184 (4.2 TB)
Present Capacity: 2008281120783 (1.83 TB)
DFS Remaining: 2008281063424 (1.83 TB)
DFS Used: 57359 (56.01 KB)
DFS Used%: 0%
Under replicated blocks: 0
Blocks with corrupt replicas: 0
Missing blocks: 0

-------------------------------------------------
Datanodes available: 2 (6 total, 4 dead)

Name: 143.215.131.246:50010
Decommission Status : Normal
Configured Capacity: 2953506713600 (2.69 TB)
DFS Used: 28687 (28.01 KB)
Non DFS Used: 1022723801073 (952.49 GB)
DFS Remaining: 1930782883840(1.76 TB)
DFS Used%: 0%
DFS Remaining%: 65.37%
Last contact: Fri Jul 18 10:31:51 EDT 2014

bin/hadoop fs -put /scratch/rkannan3/hadoop/test/pg20417.txt /user/rkannan3

bin/hadoop fs -ls /user/rkannan3
Found 1 items
-rw-------   1 rkannan3 supergroup    7420270 2014-07-18 10:40 /user/rkannan3/pg20417.txt

bin/hadoop fsck /user/rkannan3 -files -blocks -locations
FSCK started by rkannan3 from /143.215.131.246 for path /user/rkannan3 at Fri Jul 18 10:43:13 EDT 2014
/user/rkannan3 <dir>
/user/rkannan3/pg20417.txt 7420270 bytes, 8 block(s):  OK <==== All the 8 blocks in one DN
0. blk_3659272467883498791_1006 len=1048576 repl=1 [143.215.131.246:50010]
1. blk_-5158259524162513462_1006 len=1048576 repl=1 [143.215.131.246:50010]
2. blk_8006160220823587653_1006 len=1048576 repl=1 [143.215.131.246:50010]
3. blk_4541732328753786064_1006 len=1048576 repl=1 [143.215.131.246:50010]
4. blk_-3236307221351862057_1006 len=1048576 repl=1 [143.215.131.246:50010]
5. blk_-6853392225410344145_1006 len=1048576 repl=1 [143.215.131.246:50010]
6. blk_-2293710893046611429_1006 len=1048576 repl=1 [143.215.131.246:50010]
7. blk_-1502992715991891710_1006 len=80238 repl=1 [143.215.131.246:50010]
```

Comment: Seriously, 1 MB block size and replication factor of 1 while yo have TB of capacity available? Anyway, I think HDFS will try to keep blocks local from machine where you uploaded file from local FS and I think with such low usage level HDFS dosent see need for rebalancing.

Comment: Does it mean the load balancing starts only after a threshold of load in a datanode? Can't we keep always balanced?

Comment: I generated a 100MB file. It is still not getting distributed to the second datanode.

Comment: After putting 100MB file, I also ran the balancer. Still the files do not move to the next node.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have distribution on file level use at least a replication factor of 2. The first replica is always placed where the writer is located
(see the introduction paragraph  in http://waset.org/publications/16836/optimizing-hadoop-block-placement-policy-and-cluster-blocks-distribution); and normally one file has only one writer, so the first replica of several blocks of a file will always be on that node. You probably don't want to change that behaviour, because you want to have the option available to increase the minimum split size when you want to avoid spawning too many mappers without losing the data locality for mappers.

Answer (score 0):

You must use Hadoop balancer command. Details below. Tutorials [link](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/commands_manual.html#balancer)

**Balancer**

Runs a cluster balancing utility. You can simply press Ctrl-C to stop the rebalancing process. Please find more details here

```
   Usage: hadoop balancer [-threshold <threshold>]

   -threshold <threshold>   Percentage of disk capacity. This overwrites the default threshold.
```

Comment: Thank you for quick response. I ran bin/hadoop balancer. It reported 0 over and under utilized nodes and also ran to completion saying the cluster is balanced. I then rank fsck to check if the blocks moved to other datanode. All the blocks still stays in the same node. It didn't move to other second datanode. I also tried with different thresholds.

Comment: Do you have any other files in HDFS?. What is the threshold that you have specified? @RamakrishnanKannan

Comment: No. This is the only file.

Comment: I also tried with 100MB and ran the balancer. This is the only file. I am still seeing the same behavior.

Comment: did u check if the other node is sending heartbeats to Namenode? is it up an running? what threshold value have you specified?

Comment: The other node is live. Infact when i run balancer, it reports about including the other node to balance. I tried the default threshold and upto 50.